# Automatically update version info for every project in group in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have a `.groupproj` file which I use to build several projects automatically, by building the group project. I also increase the major version and add a new FileDescription via `Project > Options > Version Info` in Delphi's IDE (RAD Studio, 10.1 Berlin), but this has to be done for each and every project manually. Since new versions are frequently released this manual process becomes burdensome. Is there any way to do this automatically for every project in the group? That is, assuming the new version and file description are the same for every project in the group.

I wrote a [bash script to do this](http://paste.debian.net/hidden/86b3697d/) but it does not seem to work. When looking under `... > Version Info` in the IDE it looks correct, but when looking at properties of the executable files that are generated, under `Details`, File version and File description are incorrect when using the script, but correct when done manually. This is important because another software uses this information.

I also tried variations of the regex patterns found in the script, to no avail.

I could not find any significant differences between the `.proj` and other metadata files from the automatically and manually generated versions that would explain the issue. I cannot supply them because I do not own the rights for this project's code.

Is there any better way to do this besides resorting to a macro recorder and a clipboard manager?

Comment: AFAIK, DDevExtensions offer this functionality: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/

Comment: Don't. Your IDE is not tooled up for this. Create a proper automated build process.

Comment: @UweRaabe Perfect! If you want to add an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

We do this by including a different version.res file in our projects and turning off the version information that is added by the IDE. This "version" file sits in our project root and is referenced by all other projects.

First in the project settings uncheck the "Include version information in project" option.

Then in each dpr add a custom resource file:

```
{$R ..\version.res}
```

I use msbuild to create my version file. It starts off with a template file like this file called version.rc.template. Note that I have two different replacement strings. The embedded FILEVERSION and PRODUCTVERSION need to be a comma separated number, but I also include the "." number in the string values that users see.

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION $(NewCommaVersion)
PRODUCTVERSION $(NewCommaVersion) 
FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
FILEFLAGS 0x0L
FILEOS 0x4L
FILETYPE 0x1L
FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    BLOCK "080904B0"
    BEGIN
      VALUE "FileDescription", "Product, by Company.\0"
      VALUE "FileVersion", "$(NewBuildVersion)\0"
      VALUE "InternalName", "Product.exe\0"
      VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright \251 Company\0"
      VALUE "ProductName", "Product\0"
      VALUE "ProductVersion","$(NewBuildVersion)\0"
    END
  END

  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  BEGIN
    VALUE "Translation", 0x809,1200
  END
END
```

My msbuild process copies the template file to the real version.rc file and replaces the tokens. I have default values in the msbuild.proj file but normally they are set from the command line when I run the build.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CommaVersion>1,2,999,999</CommaVersion>  
    <BuildVersion>1.2.999</BuildVersion>
  </PropertyGroup> 

  <ItemGroup>
    <TokenValues Include="NewCommaVersion">
        <Replacement>$(CommaVersion)</Replacement>
    </TokenValues>   
    <TokenValues Include="NewBuildVersion">
        <Replacement>$(BuildVersion)</Replacement>
    </TokenValues> 
  </ItemGroup>            

  <!--===================-->
  <Target Name="SetVersion">
    <Copy SourceFiles="version.rc.template" DestinationFiles="version.rc" />  

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.Detokenise 
       TaskAction="Detokenise" TargetFiles="version.rc" 
       ReplacementValues="@(TokenValues)"
       TextEncoding="ASCII" /> 
  </Target>
```

Finally I had trouble getting Delphi to automatically rebuild my resource files (.rc -> .res). I have not tested this in several versions so it may work ok now. Because of those issues I also have a pre-build step in my projects that compiles my .rc file into the .res file:

```
brcc32 "$(PROJECTDIR)\..\version.rc"
```

I don't check in the .res file and this way the IDE does not complain on a fresh build.

Comment: Thank you, Mark! I ended up using Uwe's suggestion as it was a better fit to the current build process everyone is used to around here, but I'll try out using a version file as a possible replacement for the current build process.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you have a build process at all. Sounds like you do it from the IDE.

Comment: Yup. Not my call though.